# Java. Интерфейс командной строки

Tags: java

Как сделать интерфейс командной строки?

Мне нужно примерно вот так:

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-






                                  вывод программы







 > поле для ввода команд
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```

Случайно не знаете, как такое осуществить?

Comment: В принципе можно это все легко сделать, но вот  какое-либо оформление непосредственно после поля для ввода - вряд ли (при условии что еще там что-то будет вводиться)

Comment: Есть какие либо библиотеки для этого?

Comment: Зачем вам библиотеки какие-то? Берете и стрингами рисуете https://ideone.com/IblOap  ..... только логику отрисовки сложить куда-то в отдельный класс, чтоб не мешалась основной логике

Comment: @Антон, JCurses, Lanterna, Blacken, Charva - много их.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Это же не обертки над консолью, а уже графические библиотеки. По факту, с таким же успехом можно уже самому на awt и swing сделать, раз уж пошла такая пьянка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, можно, но зачем, если уже есть готовые библиотеки, позволяющие выполнить указанную задачу в пару-тройку строчек? Безудержное желание строить велосипеды?

Comment: @SergeyRufanov просто по факту это получается не решение поставленной задачи. Это больше сводится к "можно ли на java сделать что-то графическое". Да, можно...конец ответа)).... А вот конкретно с консолью - дело другое.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский

Comment: @SergeyRufanov
Перефразирую: поле для ввода должно находится под выводом консоли. Как ввод сделать - я уже знаю. Но вот вывод(System.out.println() каждую секунду) съедает ввод: cs604328.vk.me/v604328596/8e11/5iLOI4EtuDw.jpg И получается не красиво >:с –

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите Lanterna. Библиотека для рисования текстовых пользовательских интерфейсов.

https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna

PS Правда с документацией не очень у них, придется в примерах поковыряться

Comment: И как выводить данные в терминал? У меня же логи, а не простые всплывающие окна...

Comment: Но это же уже UI, а не чистая консоль

Answer (score 0):

Решение на основе [BeanShell](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeanShell) и [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)

BeanShell JAR - [beanshell.org/download](http://www.beanshell.org/download.html)

Мануалы по JConsole - [beanshell.org/manual/jconsole](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/jconsole.html)

Пример на основе BeanShell и JConsole:

```
 /**
     * Print prompt and echos commands entered via the JConsole
     * 
     * @param console a GUIConsoleInterface which in addition to 
     *         basic input and output also provides coloured text
     *         output and name completion
     * @param prompt text to display before each input line
     */
    private static void inputLoop(GUIConsoleInterface console, String prompt) {
        Reader input = console.getIn();
        BufferedReader bufInput = new BufferedReader(input);

        String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        console.print(prompt, Color.BLUE);

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = bufInput.readLine()) != null) {
                console.print("You typed: " + line + newline, Color.ORANGE);

                // try to sync up the console
                //System.out.flush();
                //System.err.flush();
                //Thread.yield();  // this helps a little

                if (line.equals("quit")) break; 
                console.print(prompt, Color.BLUE);
            }
            bufInput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

[Оригинальный пост](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324525/5674802)