# Java. Проблема с вводом

Tags: java

В коде программы находится таймер, который каждую секунду выводит в консоль текст.

Так же, в коде есть функция, которая ловит вводимые данные в консоли.

Проблема в том, что эти вводимые данные "покрывает" выводимый текст. 
А нужно, чтобы вводимый текст ВСЕГДА был под выводимым текстом. 
Проблема выглядит примерно вот так:

[image: Выводимый текст "покрывает" вводимую команду]

Есть ли какое-нибудь решение данной проблемы?

Comment: Синхронизация поток выводящих на консоль.

Comment: @Sergey, можно подробней?

Comment: Ошибся. Сослепу не разглядел, что во втором случае ввод. С оператором ЭВМ, который заколачивает текст, никак синхронизироваться не получится. Кстати, тут уже кто-то спрашивал про подобный интерфейс. Всем одно и тоже задание выдали? Там насоветовали кучу библиотек. Ищите java консоль

Comment: @Sergey, к примеру, запуск ядра Spigot (Minecraft), там есть курсор после текста а сверху вывод. Точно нельзя?
http://cs604328.vk.me/v604328596/904a/lK7qqUP6FwU.jpg

Кстати, я уже перерыл 10 с чем-то страниц в гугле. Ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Именно о таком и спрашивали пару-тройку дней назад

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523056/java-%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: @Sergey, там нет ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Посмотрите тогда кино [Java Tutorial - Console Like Windows Command Prompt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYSjCGKCWQQ)

Comment: @Sergey, я собираюсь использовать программу на выделенном сервере! Мне нужна только консоль, а не панели!

Comment: Размер консоли (кол-во строк, колонок) всегда одинаково или может меняться? В java нет средств узнать размеры консоли. А это нужно учитывать, чтобы вывод не перекрывал ввод. Поэтому надо применять библиотеки типа jcurses, которую советовали в прошлом вопросе. Не знаю работает ли она под виндовс, но под линухом точно. А если размер всегда одинаковый, то можно и подручными средствами обойтись.

Comment: @Sergey, копал, копал, нашёл сорсы jcurses. Впихнул в свой код. Попытался нарисовать линию - ноль эмоций. Ошибка. А знаете почему? Потому что доков нормальных нет!

Comment: Попробовал сделать на CHARVA. Получилось довольно просто. Особенно если ранее имел дело со Swing. Но существует только 32-битная версия. И как оказалось строки из таймера появляются только после нажатия на клавишу. В отличии от swing ввод здесь блокирует обработку прочих событий. Остаётся только привести свои хотелки в соответствие с возможностями. Или доработать напильником какое-либо решение для себя или выполнить с нуля.

Comment: @Sergey, какой смысл от ваших рассуждений? Я же не пойму, как вы использовали библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Бегло прочитав Вашу проблему, могу посоветовать лишь направление, в котором стоит искать решение, поскольку сам не особо представляю сейчас как можно это синхронизировать.
Однако, вам должна помочь библиотека Concurrent. Она предназначена как раз для ситуаций, подобной Вашей.

Comment: Она встроена в Java, или её нужно отдельно скачивать? Если скачивать, то дайте ссылку, пожалуйста.

Comment: Видимо Асгард не врубился в суть вопроса, как и я.

Comment: @Антон это стандартная библиотека 
[вот пример](http://prologistic.com.ua/java-lock-teoriya-i-primer-ispol-zovaniya-concurrency-lock.html)

Answer (score 1):

А не проще ли в таймере считывать текущую строку и если она не пустая, то запрещать или модифицировать вывод? Как вариант - сохранять текущее значение строки, обнулять, выводить сперва текст сообщения, а потом уже заполнять строку ввода сохраненной строкой.

Comment: Таймер таким образом будет ждать ввода и будет выводить свои строки только после ввода. Тогда зачем вообще таймер?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите одновременно и вводить и выводить из консоли?

Если вывод не нужен постоянно, а лишь подобие логов, то советую переправить его в файл, а ввод оставить консольный. Это самое простое.

Можете вывод сохранять в буфер, скажем, по 10 записей, тогда у вас будет примерно 10 секунд для ввода команды (между итерациями).

Если совсем заморочиться - можно сделать сервер-клиент, сервер - ваша прога с выводом в консоль, а клиент - может быть консоль с telnet.